# ant unable to get property value

Tags: java, ant

I have a property file(user.properties) like this:

```
vc.ip=10.161.22.102,10.161.19.112
adminUserName=admin
adminPassword=password
sshUserName=userName
sshPassword=password
```

So I have included it:

```
<property file="user.properties"/>
```

So after that I can refer `vc.ip` as ${vc.ip}.
But after that I would like to split `vc.ip` and store values(10.161.22.102 and 10.161.19.112) in different variables. How can I achieve that?

I have tried this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    project.setProperty('variable1', project.getProperty(${vc.ip}).split(',')[0]);
    project.setProperty('variable2', project.getProperty(${vc.ip).split(',')[1]);
</script>
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
        project.setProperty('vcIp', project.getProperty(${vc.ip).split(',')[0]);
                                                         ^ in <eval> at line number 2 at column number 57
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:586)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:653)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:640)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:521)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:192)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:108)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:52)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:826)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:2:57 Expected , but found {

        project.setProperty('vcIp', project.getProperty(${vc.ip}).split(',')[0]);
```

I have tried this way:

```
<script language="javascript">
    project.setProperty('variable1', project.getProperty('vc.ip').split(',')[0]);
    project.setProperty('variable2', project.getProperty('vc.ip').split(',')[1]);
</script>
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: null has no such function "split" in <eval> at line number 2
```

Comment: in first scenario your syntax is not proper .project.getProperty(${vc.ip).split(',')[0]); please check it

Comment: Why don't you just define first `variable1=10.161.22.102` and `variable2=10.161.19.112` in your users.properties and then `vc.ip=${variable1},${variable2}`? Then there is no need to split a property value.